# Are the teachers' answers to this assignment wrong?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

I answered this assignment to the best of my abilities, but I feel the "official" answers are incorrect in some places. It's a multiple choice questionnaire.

> I am sure that Huston Rockets ___ the game, if Yao Ming’s knee had not been hurt.

I chose **might have won** correct answer is **would win**

> The same thing, happening in war time, ____ great disaster.

I chose **would amount to**, correct answer is **would have amounted to**

> If I ___ the job, I would do it in a different way.

I chose **were to do**, correct answer is **would do**.

> If there were no subjunctive mood, English ____ much easier to learn

I chose **would have been**, correct answer is **would be**.

Some of these seem like they would depend on the author's intention. As both options would be accepted. Am I wrong?

Comment: Your answer is correct and the official answer is clearly wrong in the third question. I suspect that whoever wrote the quiz speaks that dialect of American English for which their answer to the third question is correct, and they don't understand the use of conditionals in standard English. So you can see that it even completely confuses some native speakers who speak a non-standard dialect.

Comment: In the first "might have won" is logically incorrect as you cannot be **sure** of something that **might** have happened - might indicates a low possibility. The second is dependent upon the context and both are possible. In the third, "would do" is strange and probably wrong; "were to do" is correct as it expresses an unreal condition. In the fourth, "would be" is correct. "would have been" assumes that the task of learning English is finite, but it is not.

Comment: @Greybeard: an English assignment where the right answer depends on processing the fact that the task of learning English is not finite is not testing you on English ability, but on logic.

Comment: @Greybeard - You are wrong about "might have been".  "Might" simply indicates a probability that was less than 100%.  Besides which, "would win" should be "would have won" in that context.

Comment: Alex, you are right that the "correct" answers are bogus.

Comment: In the first and the third case, the 'official' answers are plain wrong (assuming that the test is intended to test the candidates' knowledge of standard English). In the second and the fourth case, the right phrase to use would depend on the context and the speaker's intentions, so, if we don't know anything about that, both answers should be treated as correct.

Comment: @Greybeard, even if one interpreted *might* to indicate low probability, there would be no contradiction in saying that one is sure that something might happen: although both words concern probability, they are about different kinds of probability. If we take *might* in this example to inform us that the actual probability of winning is low, *sure* can, without contradicting that, inform us that the speaker's confidence about that low probability is high. One can have 95% confidence that the probability of something is 5%.

Comment: @jsw29 Hotlicks had a similar reaction but I would say that, e.g., "I am positive that it might work" is something that would only be said by a politician - it is, essentially, meaningless. ***I am sure** that Huston Rockets **might have won** the game, if...*  is the same thing.

Comment: @Hotlicks. I read the example as I am sure that Huston Rockets **would win** the game *tomorrow*, if Yao Ming’s knee had not been hurt.

Comment: @Greybeard - But then wouldn't Yao Ming's knee still be hurt?

Comment: Yes, It was hurt 3 days ago in training and that is why, tomorrow, he will not be in the team that needs his skills and why the team will lose and why the team will be relegated and why the manager will lose his job and turn to drink, which will cause his wife to divorce him, etc.

Comment: Can anyone provide feedback on the second one? @jsw29 What would the first answer imply, and what would the second one imply?

Comment: @AlexOsheter, the first would imply that we are talking about some possible future war, the second that we are talking about a past war.

Comment: @Greybeard, yes, it is quite likely, as a matter of **pragmatics**, that somebody who, in real life, used the sentence 'I am sure that Huston Rockets might have won the game', would be trying to weasel out of saying anything definite about the matter. But that doesn't mean that the sentence **itself** is **logically** defective. One can easily see that one's confidence about some probability is distinct from the probability itself, if one reflects on one's being 100% confident that the probability of a coin toss coming out heads is 50%.